# Basis Pursuit Denoising

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

The Lagrangian form of basis pursuit denoising

$\min_{w} ||w||_{\ell_{1}} + \lambda ||Aw-x||_{\ell_{2}}^{2}$

can be solved using proximal gradient descent.   Proximal methods also can be used to solve

$\min_{w} ||w||_{\ell_{1}} \text{  s.t.  } ||Aw-x||_{\ell_{2}}^{2} \le \epsilon$

by solving the Lagrangian form and iterating over $\lambda$ until the constraint (complementary slackness) is met.   But this could result in having to solve the Lagrangian form multiple times (for different $\lambda$) before finding the correct $\lambda$?
Is there a better approach to solving this problem?

Comment: Are you familar with the LASSO, http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/lasso/lasso.pdf ?

Comment: I've heard of it.  Is it a proximal like method?

Comment: It's a very effective method and many people have worked on it and used it. The paper has had 12,000 citations.

Comment: I agree that LASSO is probably the most well known for this particular problem, but if you want to be able to use other norms than $l_1$, then cvx is probably better.

Comment: CVX is certainly more flexible but when proximal gradient methods work, they will generally be faster and solve larger problems than CVX. I would argue that your first form above is a better choice. But what exactly do you mean by "find the correct $\lambda$"? You do understand, I hope, that the choice of $\lambda$ is just as arbitrary as the choice of $\epsilon$. You have to do cross-validation to pick the best value of either. So from that standpoint alone, one is not better than the other.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [LASSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso_(statistics)) (Least Absolute Shrinkage and Selection Operator) or the [LARS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least-angle_regression) (Least Angle Regression) solvers to solve the full path of the problem.

The idea is as following, given $ k $ coefficients, find the Least Squares solution.
Instead of continuous parameter 4 \lambda $ they solve for discrete parameter which defines the sparsity of the solution.

While still they doesn't solve the $ \epsilon $ form directly, they solve it in more efficient way if you would like to explore various values of $ \epsilon $.

Otherwise, for a direct solution you'll have to use general solvers.
CVX being a great abstraction layer above them.

By the way, on my experience, if you utilize good solver of the $ \lambda $ form (ADMM or Coordinate Descent) the problem is solved very quickly and efficiently.

Have a look at my [StackExchange Cross Validated Q291962 answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/338229/6244).